# How to make browsers reflect latest firebase service worker file code?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-cloud-messaging

In my vue app, service worker is registered automatically by getToken(provided by firebase node module) function in app.vue.
But I have to unregister service workers to reflect latest version of my service worker file
Is there any proper method of doing like changing versions  ?